# How to know if a Vue 3 reactive object is being tracked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a store pattern that contains reactive objects outside of the components that use them (I call it a store because of this page: [Vue Guide - Simple State Management](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html#simple-state-management-from-scratch)).

So, a reactive object is shared across an unknown number of components that may or may not be currently rendering content on the page.

But I have some synchronization logic that is expensive, so I only want it to run for objects in my store **that are being used**.

In Vue 2, I found an undocumented way to do this.

```
reactiveObject.__ob__.dep.subs.length
```

The **Subcribers** are visible, and if a component is no longer rendered (is not the current route in vue-router for example) then Vue 2 did a perfect job of unsubcribing when removing that component from the DOM.

I'm upgrading to Vue 3, and as far as I can tell, it called "Tracked" instead of "Subscribed" but this tracking information seems to be in a private scope (might be the ***targetMap*** variable that Vue 3's source code uses during `track()` and `trigger()`).

Is there a way to know if a Vue 3 reactive object is currently being watched?  To know if a change to that object will trigger anything?

Comment: Have you looked into isReactive https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#isreactive

Comment: Good idea @Kalimah, but isReactive is always true simply by creating the value, even if the value has never been read.  So it won't tell me if I change the value, will listening code get run?

Comment: I am not sure how this is different from what watch does in vue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a composable that tracks the number of subscribers using the Vue Effect Scope API.

```
import { ref, readonly, computed, onScopeDispose } from "vue";

export function useSubscriberTracker(value) {
  const subscribers = ref(0);

  const dispose = () => {
    subscribers.value -= 1;
  };

  return {
    useState() {
      subscribers.value += 1;
      onScopeDispose(dispose);
      return value;
    },
    subscriberCount: readonly(subscribers),
    isTracked: computed(() => subscribers.value > 0),
  };
}
```

This will return an object containing a composable named `useState()`, which will return the passed in value (which could be a reactive, ref, or whatever).

`useState()` will increment the subscriber count whenever it is called, and decrement the count when the effect scope of a consumer that called it ends.

The `subscriberCount` and `isTracked` provide reactive status of the value's subscriber count.

You then give the `useState()` composable to consumers instead of the raw state. You could export it and let consumer's import it, or you could pass it to components as a prop or something. Whatever works for you.
The only requirements are that the `useState()` function is called by the consumer itself (so it is called in the correct scope), and only once per consumer (to keep the correct subscriber count).

[Demo in Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: onScopeDispose is a great find, thanks for that!  It got me to make a SFC Playground that matches my original need.  Except oddly the way I used it threw a Vue Warn, and the functionality works as desired without onScopeDispose.  I'll post as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [demo in Vue SFC Playground that shows what the OP is aiming to do](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

The functionality works, but in a surprisingly powerful way.  Way to go Vue3!

In the process of adding a "status" observable, it turns out that when the status changes (to "up-to-date" for example), Vue re-checks the data as well.

The OP was wanting to check if an observable is used so it could hold off on doing the "expensive server call".  But since the next read happens right away, this approach waits until the data is used in a template, which will either run the update right away or wait until the data is needed.